# ASP.NET Core: How to use the Controllers of a RazorPage application as backend for a mobile app accessing the same data?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, asp.net-core-webapi

I am just doing my first steps in ASP.NET Core and after doing some tutorials I could not find an answer to a simple question:

When I've build a web application with razor pages, I've got the controllers exposing the CRUD functions.
How can I access these as backend used in a mobile app?

I want users to be able to access the functionality via website and via mobile app.

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio): *Razor Pages is a new aspect of ASP.NET Core MVC that makes coding page-focused scenarios easier and more productive.* This implies (to me) that Razor Pages is not intended to be used for APIs - for that, you'll want to use the more traditional controller approach.

Comment: In my understanding it should be possible, either using middleware, by configuring alternative routes, or something I haven't found yet. As said, I am new to this ;)

Comment: Well, even if you could reuse your existing Razor Pages, they'd have to change dynamically (in some way) to return e.g. JSON instead of HTML, CSS etc. My advice is to create a separate set of controllers (not Razor Pages) to serve as the API backend.

Comment: You are right, not because of the pages but because the mvc controllers return values are of type Task<IActionResult> and return a view; since the controllers are just accessing the context class, I came to this solution, too.

Comment: Well that's true but Razor Pages can also have `Task<IActionResult>` return types.

Answer (score 0):

Since the controllers created via "MVC Controller with views..." return values are of type Task<IActionResult> and return a view, it is not possible to use these controllers.

These controllers just access the context class, as do the API Controllers; so adding a new set of "API controller with actions..." is my solution; when creating subfolders (e.g. /MvcControllers and /ApiControllers), you can name both according the conventions, the automatically created routing lets one access the user with id 42 either by /user/Details/42 or by /api/user/42 which is pretty convenient.